# Qt unwanted double execution of a pushButton pressed signal

Tags: c++, qt

I created with Qt Creator 3.3.1 in design mode a pushButton and with the designer I connect the button with the signal pressed(). It work fine but sometimes and when I set in the pressed event a pushButton to hide or show or change the index of a stacketWidget the signal pressed() is repeated twice consecutively. I don't have connect manually in the code, but it's all done automatically by the designer. I'm using Qt 4.8.6 embedded. Thanks

```
void myclass::on_pushButton_1_pressed()
{

qDebug("Pressed event");
ui->pushButton_2->hide(); //if I comment this line the pressed signal is not repeated twice

}
```

Comment: I can imagine that the `pressed` signal is a bit special. It might act differently on different platforms, as it is probably a spontaneous event by the underlying OS. E.g. clicking on a button, draging off and on again, will emit it twice (in Windows at least). Especially when modifying the UI, I can very well imagine that this is triggered another time. I guess you're basically out of luck here... But do you really need the `pressed` signal? Won't `clicked` work, too?

Answer (score 4):

Qt designer forms have a feature called [*autoconnect*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect). It automatically connects signals of your form widgets, if there is a slot called `on_{ObjectName}_{SignalName}`.

So your slot is connected twice, once by your connection in the designer, and once by auto-connect.

Either remove your connection in designer, or rename your slot to resolve the additional call

Comment: How I can remove my connection in the designer? I work only with Qt Creator 3.3.1

Comment: It's a bit strange, only it happens with the pressed signal. The released and click signals does not suffer from this problem.

Comment: I assume that you connected the signal in designer via Drag&Drop. Is this the case? If so, you can simply select the connection in Edit Signals&Slots mode, and remove it (or via the Signals&Slots panel at the bottom).

Comment: @Memphis Open the `.ui` file in your favorite editor. Also, you don't need to be limited to Qt Creator 3.3.1: the version of Qt Creator and the version of Qt it uses in its kits are not related in any way. You can use the latest Qt Creator with any version of Qt4 or Qt5. In fact, you'll often use it with several versions and builds coexisting.

Comment: In designer mode i right-click on the pushButton and select "go to slot" and I select the slot. It exactly what I do with the buttons

Comment: @KubaOber I open .ui file but this file I don't see slot or signal.

Comment: If I remove the line with the pushButton_2->hide(); the signal pressed is repeated only once.